# AVAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined on iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, avfoundation, avcapturedevice

`[AVCaptureDevice authorizationStatusForMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio]` on iOS Simulator always returns `AVAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined`, even though an attempt to call `[AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio ...]` results in immediate granting of the permissions (*without a permissions dialog, even!*).

How can I know whether I have Microphone permissions?

Answer (score 2):

While making things work correctly on the iOS Simulator is not very important, one can check `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance.recordPermission` first, which reports reliably both on Simulator and actual devices.